# Can a constexpr function contain a label?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr

This [program](https://godbolt.org/z/1rjjhv):

```
constexpr void f() { x: ; }
```

is compiled by gcc, but clang says:

```
error: statement not allowed in constexpr function
```

So is this code valid?

Comment: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) says a `constexpr` function cannot contain a statement with a label other than `case` and `default`. Looks that comes from section 10.1.5, dcl.constexpr, from the standard.

Answer (score 7):

As pointed out in a [comment by Nathan Pierson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64852653/can-a-constexpr-function-contain-a-label#comment114659996_64852653), Clang is correct, and the code is ill-formed. According to the current working draft (which includes C++20), [dcl.constexpr#3](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#3) says:

> The definition of a constexpr function shall satisfy the following requirements:
>
> > ...
> >
> > its function-body shall not enclose
> >
> > > ...
> > >
> > > an identifier label,
> > >
> > > ...
> >
> > ...