# Why does GCC compile a constexpr function that can never result in a constant expression?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, constexpr

(compiler used is gcc with c++17 as far as I know (difficult to find this in visual studio))

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void increment( int& v )
{
    ++v;
}

int constexpr f()
{
    int v = 0;
    increment( v );
    return v;
}

int main( )
{
    cout << f( ) << '\n';
}
```

The above code gives the error on compile:

> constexpr function 'f' cannot result in a constant expression.

As I understand it this is because the function `increment` is not a constexpr. What confuses me is that the following code compiles fine:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void increment( int& v )
{
    ++v;
}

int constexpr f()
{
    int v = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < 1; ++i )
    {
        increment( v );
    }   
    return v;
}

int main( )
{
    cout << f( ) << '\n';
}
```

This code is functionally the same and it does compile, even though increment is still not a constexpr. I don't understand how it's possible that a for-loop through the range [0, 1) causes the compiler to realize that the function `f` actually is a constexpr.

If anyone can give some insights on constexpr in c++ and this apparent inconsistency, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: fwiw, same results on godbolt (gcc trunk, c++17), compiles: https://godbolt.org/z/sdM9zf error:https://godbolt.org/z/3sEbfh

Comment: FWIW, your second example **does not** compile in my copy of GCC. I get this error: "error: call to non-constexpr function ‘void increment(int&)"

Comment: @Dai which version is that?

Comment: Everything before GCC9 fails to compile [here](https://godbolt.org/z/xjr6W5).  Not sure what's going on but IMHO this should be an error and [clang agrees](https://godbolt.org/z/ET6bdj)

Comment: Using `clang -std=c++1z FILE.cpp -o FILE.o` the second example doesn't compile. Clang version 10.0.1.

Comment: This is possibly because without the loop, the analyzer can know that it will never be a constexpr. With the loop (in the generic sense, if it doesn't look at the loop bounds) it thinks that it is possible that the `increment` function will not be called and therefore `f` might be able to have a constant value.

Comment: Your second code doesn't compile with my clang++ (7.0.1), "error: constexpr function never produces a constant expression [-Winvalid-constexpr]". But I'm compiling with "-ansi -pedantic -Wall"

Comment: fwiw, even if conforming I'd consider this as bug in gcc. I mean they managed to issue a diagnostic before 9, which is nice even if not reuqired. Why not anymore?

Comment: @idclev463035818: GCC devs might consider that a bug if anyone cares to report it.  I wondered if maybe optimization / inlining was happening before checking for constexpr validity, but no, still no diagnostic with `-O0`.  (Possibly related: even when `f()` *is* a valid `constexpr` function, GCC chooses not to eval it at compile time at `-O0`. https://godbolt.org/z/MjoWoe.  I simplified the asm output by using `return f();` instead of cout<<.  But older GCC like 7.5 does that, too, and not inlining or constant-propagating (except when forced) is just normal `-O0` behaviour.)

Comment: Just a guess, in the second example the compiler might first inline the mini function void increment( int& v ), so it does not matter that it is not a constexpr... after inlining it is one

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both programs are "ill-formed no diagnostic required", per [[dcl.constexpr]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.constexpr#6):

> For a constexpr function or constexpr constructor that is neither defaulted nor a template, if no argument values exist such that an invocation of the function or constructor could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression, or, for a constructor, an evaluated subexpression of the initialization full-expression of some constant-initialized object ([[basic.start.static]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.start.static#2)), the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

It's a bit strange that gcc just fails to notice the issue with the second program, but it's still conforming.

Note a diagnostic would be required if `f` were used in a context that actually requires a constant expression, for example `constexpr int n = f();`.

Some things are never permitted in a constexpr function. These do require a diagnostic (typically an error message), even if the function is never used in a constant expression - see [cigien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65082072/459640). But the programs in the question don't violate any of these stricter rules.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, or at least incomplete. No argument values exist that allow `constexpr int g() { goto x; }` to be an "evaluated subexpression ...", but `g` is certainly not IFNDR, and the compiler is *required* to diagnose this.

Comment: @cigien You sure?  [this](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#6) look just like the OP's examples and says it is IFNDR

Comment: @cigien `goto` is explicitly not allowed, the OP, isn't using it though.

Comment: @NathanOliver Sure, the OP's code *is* IFNDR, but that's because the definition of `f` is not violating one of the diagnosable requirements. It's not automatically IFNDR because of the "no argument values exist such that ..." rule as the answer implies.

Comment: @cigien Every requirement of the Standard must be satisfied independently, sure. They're also not ill-formed because of an ambiguous overloaded function call, or etc. or etc. What I quoted explains that the program is not well-formed, and I think that's the most applicable requirement for the question. Your quote about some similar cases that do unconditionally require a diagnostic is a helpful addition to that.

Comment: @cigien This also addresses the confusion in the OP question "... causes the compiler to realize that the function `f` actually is a constexpr."

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you're saying. My feeling is that the emphasis should be the other way around. There *are* some diagnosable requirements on constexpr functions, and since none of those are violated, it falls back to IFNDR, according to the text you quoted. I prefer pointing out, if possible, why the program is not ill-formed first.

Comment: Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64852653) of what I mean. Your answer would be completely wrong for that question, but as far as I can tell, there's no reason your answer wouldn't be applicable to that question.

Comment: @cigien Added a note and link to your answer.

Comment: @cigien: IFNDR wins if you violate it as well as some other rule.  In this case, I would argue that this is a wording defect, and that “and no call to the function is evaluated in a constant expression” should be interpolated.  There are of course also cases where violating a diagnosable rule prevents interpretation of the program, where we must for sanity assume that no non-diagnosable rule is violated by whatever the ill-formed program means.

Comment: @DavisHerring I'm a little confused. Are you saying the linked code in my previous comment is IFNDR because it violates [decl.constexpr/6]? And so a diagnostic is not required?

Comment: @cigien: A label doesn’t violate [expr.const]/2, so the IFNDR rule doesn’t apply in that case.  However, IFNDR wins if you have a constexpr function that has no valid argument values even if you do call it in a constant expression.  Implementations will in practice diagnose this, since it’s free during that evaluation, but (unfortunately) they don’t *have* to.

Answer (score 6):

Since you're not calling `f` in a constant expression, your question is asking if the compiler is *required* to diagnose that `f` can't be called in a constant expression, based solely on its *definition*.

The requirements on the *definition* of a `constexpr` function are enumerated [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#3):

> The definition of a constexpr function shall satisfy the following requirements:
>
> (3.1)
> its return type (if any) shall be a literal type;
>
> (3.2)
> each of its parameter types shall be a literal type;
>
> (3.3)
> it shall not be a coroutine;
>
> (3.4)
> if the function is a constructor or destructor, its class shall not have any virtual base classes;
>
> (3.5)
> its function-body shall not enclose
>
> > (3.5.1)
> > a goto statement,
>
> > (3.5.2)
> > an identifier label,
>
> > (3.5.3)
> > a definition of a variable of non-literal type or of static or thread storage duration.

As can be seen, the definition of `f` does not violate any of the requirements in the list. So a compiler is conforming if it chooses not to diagnose this.

As pointed out in [aschepler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65082035/8372853), `constexpr` functions like `f` that can't be called in a constant expression, but are not diagnosable as such, are considered ill-formed-no-diagnostic-required.

Comment: So the part with "shall only call other constexpr functions" is no longer true?

Comment: @Surt Which text are you referring to exactly?

Comment: Seem to remember that the first version of constexpr was extremely limited and one of the requirements was that it only called other constexpr functions.

Comment: @Surt Oh, that's C++11 I think. You can do much more now, especially from C++20 :)

Comment: @Surt A constexpr function can call non-constexpr functions in general, but when it's used in a context requiring a constant expression, all the functions actually called must be marked constexpr. It's now a requirement on "constant expression" rather than "constexpr function".

Comment: where in the standard does it say what version it is? Subtitle says "Generated 2020", but I suppose this is C++17, right?

Comment: @idclev463035818 It's the working draft, so it has C++20 in it.

Comment: note that the question specifically asks for C++17. Did something change in between on this part?

Comment: @idclev463035818 Ah, true. I don't remember if anything's changed in-between. I'll take a look and edit if anything meaningful was changed. If there are just some added diagnostics, I'll leave the answer, since I don't think the OP cares about exactly the C++17 spec.

Comment: well actually I don't believe it will change much about the answer, just asking out of curiosiry

Comment: @idclev463035818 No, it's a good question, a *lot* of stuff changed re constexpr, so it's worth checking. Though I'm pretty sure there are no changes that are relevant here.

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually "calling" `f` at compile time.

if your main function included:
`static_assert(f() == 1, "f() returned 1");` I suspect you would get an "f() is not a constant expression" error.

Here's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33716507/how-can-this-code-be-constexpr-stdchrono)

Comment: Indeed, https://godbolt.org/z/dar4Gv shows `error: non-constant condition for static assertion` instead of just doing constant-propagation.  As well as the more revealing: `in 'constexpr' expansion of 'f()'` / `error: call to non-'constexpr' function 'void increment(int&)'`.  So apparently GCC is applying the concept of evaluating the function in the context of a constexpr expression / context, being much more permissive otherwise.  This is perhaps a useful C++ extension for functions with args, allowing calls to non-constexpr functions protected by an `if` that's only true in non-const cases.

Answer (score 0):

The standard requires that a `constexpr` function actually be evaluable at compile time for *some* set of parameters but not all. It does not require compilers to diagnose a `constexpr` function doing certain things which might be non-compile-time in some circumstances, or even whether such a function has such a set of parameters. This avoids them having to solve the halting problem.

Comment: but there are not parameters in either of them. The loop is executed exactly once, no?

Comment: `f` only has one set of parameters - the empty set.

Comment: That’s not the point. Because it would be impossible for a compiler to reliably prove whether a function could be evaluated at compile time, the standard does not require it to do so. There’s no exception made for specific easy cases.

Comment: i mean without parameters, either they are evaluable at compile time for all possible parameters or for none. I might be wrong, but why?

Comment: The compiler can and does know that `for( int i = 0; i < 1; ++i )` will execute once, since it's all compile time info.  That means `increment` must be called, and since it is not `constexpr`, `f` is not either.

Comment: No, you’re right. But the standards committee chose not to complicate the language by including an exhaustive set of weird edge cases where non-constexpr-ness could be straightforwardly proven and requiring that compiler diagnose that set. (I think that was the right move on their part.)

Comment: are you saying that `constexpr` is a promise, in some sense like `const` ? I am promising not to apply a `const_cast` and modify something that is `const` / I claim that there exist parameters that allow to evaluate the function at compile time?

Comment: I’m saying that the compiler is allowed to not be smart enough to diagnose this error.

Comment: thanks for your patience. Now I wonder what the downvotes are for. Maybe the first senctence is too prominent, for me it caused a bit of confusion

Comment: I was impressed by the sheer rate of voting activity :-D

Comment: "*It does not require compilers to diagnose a constexpr function doing non-compile-time things*". This is not correct. There are non compile time things that the compiler is required to diagnose, it's just that `f` doesn't do any of them.

Comment: @Sneftel yeah it was quite some roller-coaster up down :D